# What is "table_id" in MySQL binary log events?

Tags: mysql, binary-log

Is there any description for table_id in MySQL binary log events? Is it a unique value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51873/replication-binary-log-parsingtableid-generation-on-delete-cascade-handling)

> This value comes from an incrementing global counter in sql/sql_base.cc. It increments every time a table is added to the cache of open tables that is limited in size by the global variable open_table_cache... so if that value is smaller than the number of tables being periodically accessed, you should see it increment more frequently. All of the tables will have a new id on the next generated binlog event after a FLUSH TABLES.

Comment: Thanks Hendrik..!! I searched this a lot and couldn't find an informatic answer like the post that you shared. (y)